# How to choose a path for a csv file to load it into database MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to run a database only locally on my CPU. 
I'm trying to make a form where I will choose a file to load into my DB.

The problem is the file has to be in my bin\mysql\data\test folder.

How can I make it work wherever my file is?

I have one file:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="testing.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select file to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And testing.php is

```
<?php
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysqli_select_db($link, "test");

    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
        $file = ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

        $query_file =   "LOAD DATA INFILE '$file'
                INTO TABLE pomiar
                FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' '
                IGNORE 1 LINES 
                (numer, data, czas)";
        $res  = mysqli_query($link, $query_file) or die(mysql_error());
    } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify non-relative path or instead  `$file = ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);` use `$file = ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);`

Comment: But when I used tmp_name and clicked SEND I see blank white page

Comment: What else do you expect to see if you have got no output echoing in your script?

Comment: Just check if data was imported into your database.

Comment: Oh, sorry I have output but I didnt copy it here.
And no, data was not importer ;/
when I use name instead of tmp_name and I have a file in bin then it works and imports the data.

Comment: Replace `$res  = mysqli_query($link, $query_file) or die(mysql_error());` with `$res  = mysqli_query($link, $query_file) or die(mysqli_error());` and tell me what the error message says.

Comment: you forgot a parameter for mysqli_error :P

but erros is File 'F:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\data\wamp mpphp1E8C.tmp' not found (Errcode: 22 - Invalid argument)